# Change label text after Thread.Sleep

Tags: multithreading, wait

I have a sign in system running at my school, and when a student signs in, it shows a welcome message and after 5 seconds, this welcome message is erased to be replaced by, "Please swipe your student card". I have a sleep thread running. I want the welcome label to reset to say "Please swipe your ID card" after the sleep thread has finished, but it won't do it. Any help? Am I going about this the right way? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't given any details so we need to guess at the exact cause of the problem. I'm going to assume that you are using C# on Windows.

I'd guess that you are trying to perform user interface code from a worker thread which is an error. User interface code should run in the main thread.

Whilst this could be solved with `Control.Invoke` a much better approach is to avoid any threads, use a timer for your 5 second wait and perform the UI update in the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

Which language?
Whats your code ?

You could also use a timer and assign a new text to the label when the timer ticks.